# Returning true on Link Click Event isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, google-tag-manager

I am trying to execute some code that has a callback when clicking on specific links. The callback is to click the link again, but on the second pass, the method returns true to follow normal behavior. But for some reason, it's not working? I use `clickedLink` for proper scope. In the event callback, `this` was referring to `window`.

**UPDATE** 
For a little more clarity, I agree normally this wouldn't be an optimal solution, but I am using Google's Tag Manager to monitor eCommerce traffic. I am trying to make sure product clicks get pushed to their dataLayer, and using their event callback to resume normal behavior. More info here: https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/enhanced-ecommerce#product-clicks

This is my updated method based on the answers below, but it still doesn't work.

```
var shopCartBtnClicked = false;
var clickedLink;
jQuery('#pdp_add_cart, .add_to_cart_button').click(function(e) {

    if (shopCartBtnClicked === true) {
        shopCartBtnClicked = false; //I make it here just fine
    } else {
        e.preventDefault();
        clickedLink = this;
        var pdp = false;
        if (mmProduct) {
            //On detail page
            mmProduct.qty = jQuery('input[name="quantity"]').val();
            pdp = true;
        } else {
            //on a shopping page
            mmProduct = findProductClicked(this);
            mmProduct.qty = 1;
        }

        dataLayer.push({
            'event': 'addToCart',
            'ecommerce': {
                'currencyCode': 'USD',
                'add': {
                    'products': [{
                        'name': mmProduct.name,
                        'id': mmProduct.id,
                        'price': mmProduct.price,
                        'quantity': mmProduct.qty
                    }]
                }
            },
            'eventCallback': function () {
                //Are we on a product detail page with a form, or just a shopping page with a link?
                if (pdp) {
                    jQuery('form.cart').submit(); //This part works just fine
                } else {
                    mmProduct = null;
                    shopCartBtnClicked = true;
                    $(clickedLink).trigger('click'); //This doesn't
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK guys, thank you for helping me get there. Normally, all of the other answers would work great, but for this specific tag manager instance, it appears (for some unknown reason), document.location works in the event callback fine here. This works.

It's weird because I used `$(this).('form.cart').submit();` in a callback earlier in the code.

```
'eventCallback': function () {
     //Are we on a product detail page with a form, or just a shopping page with a link?
     if (pdp) {
        jQuery('form.cart').submit();
     } else {
        mmProduct = null;
        document.location = $(clickedLink).attr('href');
        //$(clickedLink).trigger('click');
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Its not very well done, but this should work:

```
var shopCartBtnClicked = false;
var clickedLink;
jQuery('.add_to_cart_button').click(function(e) {
    if (shopCartBtnClicked === true) {
        shopCartBtnClicked = false;
        // dont return, just let javascript handle this one
    } else {
        // only execute when you have not set it to true
        e.preventDefault();
        clickedLink = this;

        shopCartBtnClicked = true;
        $(clickedLink).trigger('click');
    }
});
```

I do have to wonder why you don't just execute your other logic first and then ***not** prevent default* anyway.

Comment: I am making a data layer push to Google Analytics & Tag Manager where I use their callback function. This is my way of making sure the data gets collected before moving on.

Comment: Reasonable enough :) @A.Wolff nice one.

Comment: Yeah, I tried this too, for some reason, it's not working for me. It's weird, because I do this type of operation on another link click somewhere else on the site.

Comment: It depends if Googles code gets run before yours and cancels it out. It might. Hard to say. Check google documentation to see if they have any callbacks you can use, I know `omniture` does so I guess Google Analytics should as well.

Answer (score 2):

Taking @somethinghere's answer, your code can further be simplified to improve readability:

```
var shopCartBtnClicked = false;
jQuery('.add_to_cart_button').click(function(e) {
    if( shopCartBtnClicked ) {
        shopCartBtnClicked = false;
        // dont return, just let javascript handle this one
    } else {
        // only execute when you have set it to true
        e.preventDefault();

        shopCartBtnClicked = true;
        this.click();
    }
});
```

Or, as suggested by @Regent:

```
var shopCartBtnClicked = false;
jQuery('.add_to_cart_button').click(function(e) {
    shopCartBtnClicked = !shopCartBtnClicked;
    if( shopCartBtnClicked ) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.click();
    }
});
```

Comment: Shoudl it be `this.click` or `$(this).click` ? I'm not sure. I think the latter, haven't really tried the former...

Comment: I've updated my question to give more information and entire method.

Comment: @PeterKA What about `shopCartBtnClicked = !shopCartBtnClicked;` and `if (shopCartBtnClicked) { e.preventDefault(); this.click(); }` ? Simplier and shorter.

Comment: I tried this as well, but it didn't work on second pass. I am guessing this is a tag manager issue now...

Comment: I would tend to think this was a tag manager issue, but their event callback is executing this click method a second time, and it's executing like we all would think it would, but nothing is happening. It doesn't load the new URL...

Comment: I don't know if I fully understand your explanation. You may want to look into `event.stopImmediatePropagation()` if you would like no other handlers to fire, `domElement.click()` if you just want to call the DOM `.click()` and not the jQuery `.click()`, `window.location = domElement.href` to follow the URL.

Comment: Are you sure? Let me rethink it ..... do likewise ... if before `shopCartBtnClicked` is changed it was `if( shopCartBtnClicked )` ... should it not be `if( !shopCartBtnClicked )` after it is changed? @Regent?